# Powershell and regex to parse config and display interface with ospf configured

Tags: powershell

Help please.  I want the output to display

```
interface vlan1 is not configured with ospf
interface vlan3 is configured with ospf
interface vlan7 is configured with ospf
```

but the output I got when running this script below is

```
interface vlan1 interface vlan3 interface vlan7 is configured with ospf
```

---

```
$interface = select-string -path c:\doc\config.txt -pattern "interface\vlan\d{1,3} -context 0, 3

$ospf = Select-string -inputobject $interface -pattern "ip ospf message-digest.*" | % {$_.matches.value}
if ($ospf -ne $null)
{
   $int = $ interface | select -expandproperty line #don't want to show line#
   write-host "$int is configured with ospf"
}
else
  {
    $int = $ interface | select -expandproperty line #don't want to show line#
     Write-host "$int is not configured with ospf"
  }
```

---

```
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan3
 ip ospf message-digest-key 100 md5 7 aa93naf
!
interface Vlan7
 standby 38 preempt
 ip ospf message-digest-key 100 md5 7 asf9394
```

Comment: awesome, it works.  Can you explain the last line how it works and why it has to use the -raw?    thanks     "{0} {1} configured with ospf" -f ($interface -split "`r?`n")[0],$ospf

Comment: Actually I have several configs in a folder and I want to loop thru each config and each interface to find a match for "ip ospf message-digest-key".  If each interface has the ip ospf message-digest-key" configured then I want to output those particular interfaces only.  I tired but it only output the first ip ospf message-digest-key that it found a match on the first interface only.  It didn't output the ip ospf message-digest-key for the rest of the interfaces that were configured with it.  Does anyone have a solution, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is IMO overcomplicated,

1. split the config file into chunks(interfaces) separated by the `!`,
2. check each single interface for the ospf string,
3. select the first line of the current interface and output with the test result.

---

```
## Q:\Test\2019\03\08\SO_55056710.ps1
$interfaces = (Get-Content .\config.txt -Raw) -split "!`r?`n"

foreach($interface in $interfaces){
    if ($interface -match "ip ospf message-digest"){
        $ospf = "is"} else {$ospf = "is not"}
    "{0} {1} configured with ospf" -f ($interface -split "`r?`n")[0],$ospf
}
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\03\08\SO_55056710.ps1
interface Vlan1 is not configured with ospf
interface Vlan3 is configured with ospf
interface Vlan7 is configured with ospf
```